# How to get the identity upon password login in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET identity, and below code to login user

```
SignInStatus result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.EmployeeNo, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

It works, the user is successfully logged in. But then when I check the user identity like below

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity
```

There is no data in it? How do I retrieve the identity of the user right after password login succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. To get it, just use below code

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity
```